# install python in php appengine in gcp

Tags: python, php, google-app-engine

I am trying to run a python script through PHP in a PHP appengine, I did a helloworld script which runs locally from PHP using:

```
$command = escapeshellcmd("python test.py");
$output = shell_exec($command);
```

but when I send this to the appengine and try to trigger I get the following message in the service logs:

```
WARNING: [pool app] child 16 said into stderr: "sh: 1: python: not found"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with App Engine.  You'll need to add a Python service to your App Engine app or rewrite the Python code in PHP.

Comment: can I create another service such that the first one (written in PHP) calls it to do some data engineering stuff, so first service will act like a trigger to the second one?

Comment: yes you can have two services one calling the other